# SecurityContextHolder return wrong user context on concurrent request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, concurrency

I am experiencing a weird problem, When multiple concurrent requests comes to a controller`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()`
returns same user object sometimes even if the JWT token is different.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/users/{userId}/solveDetail/create"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<CreateSolveDetail> createSolve(@PathVariable("userId") Long userId, @RequestBody CreateSolveDetail createSolveDetail){
        User user =SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    }
```

So far tried changing session management to `.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)` and thread strategy is set to `SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_THREADLOCAL)` still the isssue persists.

Below is the WebSecurityConfig class configured and a custom filter is added which overrides getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal and getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal of AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityBasicConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint http403ForbiddenEntryPoint;
    @Bean
    public Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint http403ForbiddenEntryPoint() {
        return new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(http403ForbiddenEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(preAuthFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_THREADLOCAL);
    }
}
```

```
public class PreAuthFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        String auth = httpServletRequest.getHeader("PRE-AUTH");
        try {
            User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(auth, User.class);
            return user;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new User();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        String auth = httpServletRequest.getHeader("PRE-AUTH");
        return auth;
    }
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.
Thanks in advance.

**Spring boot version** : 2.1.6.RELEASE
**Architecture**: Microservice

Comment: I have followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555559/using-static-methods-with-spring-security-to-get-current-user-details thread to do the fix but its not working

Comment: @dur
 Thanks it helped, it seems the root cause is while there are concurrent requests ```httpServletRequest.getHeader("PRE-AUTH")``` returning wrong token, seems httpServletRequest is getting overriden by next request. Any idea how to fix this. ?

Comment: @dur i found the root cause, the problem is with the WebClient.
i was trying to hit concurrent request from a different microservice which uses WebClient to call the api, when i changed it to RestTemplate the issue got resolve.

Thanks for heading me to correct direction, its an issue with the client